# Compiling libarchive for iOS?

Tags: ios, libarchive

I have cloned project from https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive, and have build it for mac, both arm64 and x86_64. I want to use libarchive in my iOS application. I have seen few projects here and there, that do exactly this, but unfortunately they are 10+ years old, and I can't make them work.

Since it has been done, I know it is possible, but does anyone know how this can be done?

**EDIT:** As per comment:
Well I will start at first step. I copied all the .c and .h files, including config.h. When I try to compile it says that lzma.h is missing. I tried a lot of stuff, like adding liblzma.tbd in link with binary libraries phase, but nothing. It seems stuck. I don't know where this lzma.h file should be coming from?

Comment: This question is to open ended. Try to narrow it down. What have you tried? What error occurred?